# How do you use F1 help in Delphi 2007?

Tags: delphi, chm

In my application, originally built with Delphi 7, I use the SPHelpIntegration code to enable CHM help via the F1 interface. I figured that this wasn't needed in Delphi 2007, so I removed the units and built my app. I then press F1 and get a message that no help interface is installed. The online help doesn't tell me a lot about what is needed to make F1 help work. Do I have to include a unit or something? Or should I just carry on doing what works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add HTMLHelpViewer to your uses clause to handle CHM files.  There is an issue in using them is they must exist on the local system (not a network share) to view properly.  There is a registry hack to change this behavior, but I have found it easier to just install the help files locally on the system.

Lately rather than CHM files, I used the [Adobe OpenPDFParameters API](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDFOpenParameters.pdf) calling conventions to throw them directly into my PDF version of my printed manual jumping to the section based on the current form (I grab the form class name and use it in my named sections).  It requires that the workstation has a PDF reader, but who doesn't now days?

Comment: The "registry hack" is just the IE Internet Options / Security. You can change this interactively, too. It applies to any web page, not just CHMs. We also copy CHMs local, though.

Comment: HTMLHelpViewer in the main project file was all that was needed, no path or anything.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to [include a help viewer in the uses clause](http://www.helpscribble.com/delphi-bcb.html).